# How would i retrieve the rows from Select Statement

Tags: php

I need to store the rows in an array but can't seem to get it to work, the code is below:
I am sure $result = $stmt->get_result(); does not work.

When i test in the browser output is empty.

```
<?php

include "connect.php";


$uid = $_REQUEST["U_ID"];


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM U_User WHERE U_ID = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("d", $uid);
$stmt->execute();
    $stmt->fetch();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
      $users[] = $row;
    }
$stmt->close();


$arr = array('user' => $users);

echo json_encode($arr);

mysqli_close($conn);

?>
```

Comment: Where does SQL Injection come in?

Comment: Is the U_ID column an integer or a double? Also, I think the $stmt->fetch() is unnecessary.

Comment: If the output is empty, then not even the final JSON generation succeeded. Enable `error_reporting`.

Comment: You are closing your connection before echoing?

Comment: no luck mate, removed that n still no output

Comment: should really be int value shall i change it to 'i'

Comment: `$stmt->fetch();`, `$result = $stmt->get_result();`, AND `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` **?** I believe each one moves the internal pointer forward after each call, so the last one -> `while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())` is trying to return a 3rd result, and I am guessing your query only returns 1.

Comment: yes only returns one but i am going to create multiple statements which will return more than one

Comment: I'm sorry for my misleading answer, I didn't notice you were using mysqli instead of PDO. I would really advice you to switch to PDO, it's much easier once you get the hold of it.

Comment: no worries @php_nub_qq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like php_nub_qq said. I switched to PDO works great.

```
<?php

        include "connect.php";


        $uid = $_REQUEST["U_ID"];

        $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM U_User WHERE U_ID = :uid");
        $q->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
            $users[] = $r;
        }


        $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM P_Post u WHERE P_U_ID = :uid");
        $q->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
            $posts[] = $r;
        }


        $q = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM T_Thread u WHERE T_U_ID = :uid");
        $q->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
        $q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while ($r = $q->fetch()) {
            $threads[] = $r;
        }




        $arr = array('user' => $users, 'post' => $posts, 'thread' => $threads);

        echo json_encode($arr);

        $conn = null;


    ?>
```